# require package in nodejs replacement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to create a package in express nodejs that use some code from dronestream package.
I found in the server.js file there is a call

```
require("dronestream").listen(3001);
```

So, I don't know when this package is called,  which is the first file to be executed and how this file can listen to a port?

In case I'm running this server.js file from my own package, what should I replace instead of require("dronestream")

I tried using app or server but it doesn't work, any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the [`dronestream` package it exports a function `listen`](https://github.com/bkw/node-dronestream/blob/master/lib/server.js#L9)

```
module.exports.listen = function listen(server, options) {
```

If you check dronestream npm package page https://www.npmjs.com/package/dronestream you will see that there is a [link to Github](https://github.com/bkw/node-dronestream). The package is called `dronestream` but on Github they call it `node-dronestream`.

In this project you can see the `package.json` file, it contains `"main": "index"`. So when you `require('dronestream')` it will import things from the index file.

The index file has the following

```
module.exports = require("./lib/server");
```

It imports things exported on the file `/lib/server.js` and exports again.

So when you `require('dronestream')` it gets things that have been exported (`module.exports`).

`require('dronestream')` will return an object with the property `listen` which is a function.

You can understand more about modules if you [read Node.js documentation on modules here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html).

If what you want is to create a server and listen on a port [you can use the package `express`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express)

Comment: Exactly this happening in the node-droestream but I'm using https://github.com/johnghantous/dronestream which doesn't have the listen function so is there any conflict or any other explanation? the calling is in camera-feed.js in drone directory , thanks for your answer

Comment: The `dronestream` package on npm is linked to the github I posted... https://www.npmjs.com/package/dronestream

Comment: so after all the calling is done to the node-dronestream and not to the one that I mentioned?

Comment: If you are using the `dronestream` installed with `npm install dronestream` then yes, it references the Github I mentioned.

Comment: yes, I installed droestream and I'm not using node-dronestream so I want to understand when using require('dronestream').listen so it's calling itself or it's calling the one node-dronestream because first it listen to 3001 and the server is listen to 8000     var express = require('express')
    , app = express()
    , server = require("http").createServer(app)

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

module.exports.listen(3001);
//require("./routes/lib/camera-feed");
//require("./drone/controller");

app.listen(8000);

Comment: If you check dronestream npm package page https://www.npmjs.com/package/dronestream you will see that there is a link to Github. The package is called `dronestream` but on Github they call it `node-dronestream`. I will update the answer with more info.